# how to bind ListView to Dictionary with a custom Value class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**Update:**

I have tried @Jason his suggestion to have it all in 1 API call

The code for it:

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string, Cost>> GetCoinsAndPrice()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                string coinurl = $"{BASEURI}public/currency";

                
                string coinjson = await client.GetStringAsync(coinurl);
                if (coinjson != null)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, Coin> coin = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary < string, Coin >>(coinjson);
                    Debug.WriteLine("coinnn" + coin.Values);

                        string priceurl = $"{BASEURI}public/price/rate?from={coin.Keys}&to=BTC";
                        string pricejson = await client.GetStringAsync(priceurl);
                        if (pricejson != null)
                        {
                            return  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Cost>>(pricejson);
                        //JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Cost>>(pricejson);

                      
                    }
                        return null;
                    
                }
                return null;
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
        }
```

updated Xaml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:user ="clr-namespace:ProjectCrypto.Views"
    x:Class="ProjectCrypto.Views.Overview">
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gold">
            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Crypto coins" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" Margin="2,16"/>
            <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="lvwOverview" RowHeight="100">
               
                <ListView.ItemTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Cost}">
                
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Key}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Label x:Name="lvwPrice" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Value.price}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text=">" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,16,0" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
               
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I now got an issue with how I access the price with Binding. Everything I'm trying is not working.

`Dictionary<string, Cost>` is what I am accessing and the price should be in cost.

Cost class:

```
 public class Cost
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "currency")]
        public string currency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "price")]
        public double price { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timestamp")]
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

    }
  
}
```

The JSON response has this structure for costs:

```
    {
  "ETH": {
    "currency": "BTC",
    "price": "0.021084",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-02T17:52:36.731Z"
  }
}
```

The JSON response for Coins:

```
 {
  "BTC": {
    "full_name": "Bitcoin",
    "payin_enabled": true,
    "payout_enabled": true,
    "transfer_enabled": true,
    "precision_transfer": "0.00000001",
    "networks": [
      {
        "network": "btc",
        "protocol": "",
        "default": true,
        "payin_enabled": true,
        "payout_enabled": true,
        "precision_payout": "0.00000001",
        "payout_fee": "0.000900000000",
        "payout_is_payment_id": false,
        "payin_payment_id": false,
        "payin_confirmations": 1,
        "low_processing_time": "21.709",
        "high_processing_time": "3639.385",
        "avg_processing_time": "421.6391704545454"
      }
    ]
  },
  "USDT": {
    "full_name": "Tether",
    "payin_enabled": true,
    "payout_enabled": true,
    "transfer_enabled": true,
    "precision_transfer": "0.01",
    "networks": [
      {
        "network": "BTC",
        "protocol": "OMNI",
        "default": true,
        "payin_enabled": true,
        "payout_enabled": true,
        "precision_payout": "0.01",
        "payout_fee": "45.000000000000",
        "payout_is_payment_id": false,
        "payin_payment_id": false,
        "payin_confirmations": 2,
        "low_processing_time": "3.291",
        "high_processing_time": "1495.602",
        "avg_processing_time": "85.98873076923078"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think because you are LoadData(); in Overview and OverviewViewCell both ?

Comment: `OverviewViewCell` sounds like a cell in a grid. So you call LoadData() for every cell in a grid?

Comment: @Charles that could be it! wondering how I would do it in the overview.xaml.cs though since i can't call the lvwPrice property in there. or how i would fix it

Comment: MVVM would be a better way to solve this. google `xamarin forms mvvm listview`. Learn how to work with a list of items in a viewmodel.

Comment: I addressed this in my comment to your previous question

Comment: can't you make a single API call that loads coins and their prices, instead of individually requesting a price for each coin?  This is very inefficient

Comment: @Jason posted an update, could you help out again? :)

Comment: please take the time to properly format your code so that it is readable.  You are using a `Dictionary`, which has two properties, `Key` and `Value`.  You want the `Price` (capital-P, not "price") property of the `Value`.  So try `Binding Value.Price`

Comment: I tried Value.Price and it did not work sadly. also noticed it only got the first coin and not all coins

Comment: is your service returning ALL the coins?  Is your data getting deserialized correctly?

Comment: I Just can't figure out how I can access the properties <Dictionary<string,Root> from the Root Class. Value.price doesnt work

Comment: What is `Root`?  You have a `Dictionary<string,Cost>` according to what you posted.  You did not answer either question I asked in my last comment.

Comment: I just tested binding to a Dictionary using the `Value.PropertyName` syntax and it worked fine for me.  Again, are you positive your Dictionary actually contains the data you think it does?

Comment: I used https://json2csharp.com/ to make sure my class was right it's now called Root

Comment: Please update your post to reflect that.  And, as I already requested, please fix the formatting.  And for about the third time, have you verified your data is correct?

Comment: trying again with original class now.. I will be verifying, one sec.

Comment: ok when i try to log the disctionaries i can't see if there is actually data in it.
what it logs is System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,ProjectCrypto.Models.Coin]

Comment: Updated the code and formatting aswell

Comment: *"when i try to log the disctionaries i can't see if there is actually data in it."* - Google `c# loop through dictionary`.

Comment: or learn to use the debugger

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple example of binding a `ListView` to a `Dictionary`.  You can use the binding expression `Value.Property` to bind to the properties of the Dictionary's `Value` - ie, `Value.Cost` or `Value.Name` for my example

```
<ListView x:Name="lv">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Key}" Detail="{Binding Value.Cost}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and the code behind

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Cost { get; set; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dictionary<string, Test> dict = new Dictionary<string, Test>();

        dict.Add("1", new Test { Name = "One", Cost = 1.0 });
        dict.Add("2", new Test { Name = "Two", Cost = 2.0 });
        dict.Add("3", new Test { Name = "Three", Cost = 3.0 });
        dict.Add("10", new Test { Name = "Ten", Cost = 10.0 });

        lv.ItemsSource = dict;
    }
```